# Move Fault From Soap Body into Soap Head with Spring WS

Tags: java, spring, soap, spring-ws, fault

What is the best way to move the soap fault found in the soap body to the soap head of a response found in Spring web services?  Any examples out there?

I can intercept the fault but I dont think I can modify anything with this resolver.

```
public class LisSoapFaultTranslatorExceptionResolver extends SoapFaultMappingExceptionResolver {

    @Override
    protected void customizeFault(Object endpoint, Exception ex, SoapFault fault) {

        fault = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to do it like this by adding items to the header.

**Spring configuration file:**

```
<sws:interceptors>    
    <sws:payloadRoot
    namespaceUri="http://www.imsglobal.org/services/lis/cmsv1p0/wsdl11/sync/imscms_v1p0">
        <bean class="com.openclass.adapter.interceptors.LisResponseInterceptor"/>    
    </sws:payloadRoot>  
</sws:interceptors>
```

**Java code:**

```
public class LisResponseInterceptor extends EndpointInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint{
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint){
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint){

        SoapMessage response = (SoapMessage) messageContext.getResponse();
        SoapHeader header = response.getSoapHeader();
        header.addHeaderElement(new QName("ims","imsx_syncRequestHeaderInfo"));

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/soap/soap_fault.asp),

> The optional SOAP Fault element is used to indicate error messages.
>
> If a Fault element is present, it must appear as a child element of the Body element. A Fault element can only appear once in a SOAP message.

If your SOAP fault is in the head of the response, your SOAP envelope no longer follows the specification. You should not do that. And I doubt a framework that implements the SOAP interface even lets you do that.

To be recognized as carrying SOAP error information, a SOAP message MUST contain a single SOAP Fault element information item as the only child element information item of the SOAP Body .

From the [Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-soap12-part1-20070427/#soapfault)

> To be recognized as carrying SOAP error information, a SOAP message
>   MUST contain a single SOAP Fault element information item as the only
>   child element information item of the SOAP Body .
>
> When generating a fault, SOAP senders MUST NOT include additional
>   element information items in the SOAP Body . A message whose Body
>   contains a Fault plus additional element information items has no
>   SOAP-defined semantics.
>
> A SOAP Fault element information item MAY appear within a SOAP header
>   block, or as a descendant of a child element information item of the
>   SOAP Body ; in such cases, the element has no SOAP-defined semantics.

The important part is `the element has no SOAP-defined semantics` if you do this. I think you're on your own for this one. Maybe use Spring to generate the SOAP response if there is no fault, otherwise generate it yourself.

Comment: We are following a spec that does just this, http://www.imsglobal.org/lis/lisv2p0/LISv2p0BestPracticev1p0.html. "The SOAP faults are reported in the SOAP header.  This means that when a SOAP request message is issued the response message may contain SOAP fault codes with no further useful information. "

Comment: I know what you mean, but I can argue with their spec. I just want a solution buddy.

Comment: **One** solution is to write the SOAP response yourself when there is a fault.

Comment: Well I was thinking I could modify the message context parameter going into my web service, but I thought it would be cleaner to throw an exception, catch it, and then modify the header.  Exceptions include things like required fields missing.

Comment: I have no experience with Spring-WS, do you have access to the response `OutputStream` before it gets flushed?